# font color changing to white instead of gray

Tags: vba, excel

I'm still learning how to code, but I just don't get why I'm failing in such a simple task that I have already done a lot of times.

The code is supposed to change the font color to gray, but it changes to white instead.

```
For j = 1 To 12

With wsTank.Cells(first(i), j)

.Value = "NIL"

With .Font
 .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
 .TintAndShade = -0.499984740745262
End With
With .Interior
 .Pattern = xlNone
 .TintAndShade = 0
 .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
 .LineStyle = xlContinuous
 .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
 .TintAndShade = 0
 .Weight = xlHairline
End With
With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
 .LineStyle = xlContinuous
 .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
 .TintAndShade = 0
 .Weight = xlHairline
End With
End With


Next j
```

I have searched a lot online, and found a person with a similar problem:

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26937588/Excel-vba-font-color-keeps-shoeing-white-instead-of-gray.html

After a few tries of someone willing to help, he got it right.

But I just don't understant his explanation... And therefore, I am not succeeding in apply it to my case.

Could someone please enlighten me?

(This issue is happening with excel 2010. The code work just fine in excel 2013)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer in your link was to not use `Themecolor` at all but use `Color` with an RGB value instead:

```
With .Font
     .Color = &H808080
     .TintAndShade = 0
end with
```

Comment: I thought that "Forecast" thing that he mentioned was the key...

I will try your code, tanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

This should work on any version of Excel.

`.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)`

The `xl...` statements can differ across the versions as they make changes.

Comment: So the problem is the     xlThemeColorDark1?

Comment: Mostly, yes.  Also the  `.TintAndShade = -0.499984740745262` it basically tints the main color by that number. Setting that to `0` may help as well, but I prefer to just use something I can control and understand more easily.